# Selecting a select option with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that is setup from database content as well as a select option that is setup from the same database. I would like to be able to click the button or choose from the dropdown to chose the option.

I have tried a lot of different options that I have found online. Currently I am able to alert the text I want to select but have been unable to change the dropdown.

```
PHP file
$q = "SELECT CONCAT(user_first, ' ', user_last) AS name1, user_id as id           from users ";
$r = @mysqli_query($conn, $q); 
// Count the number of returned rows:
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if ($num > 0) { // If it ran OK, display the records.

echo '<select class="select" name="name1" id="Seltherapist" autofocus   tabindex="1">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">' . $row['name1'] .   '</option>
    ';}
echo '</select>'; 
mysqli_free_result ($r); 
 } else { 
echo '<p class="error">There are currently no registered users.</p>';
}       


$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if ($num > 0) { 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<button name="name22" value="'.$row['name'].'"   id="'.$row['id'].'" class="btn">' . $row['name'] . '</button>
    ';}


JavaScript File

$('button[name="name22"]').click(function(){
alert($(this).attr("value"));
alert($(this).attr("id"));
event.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not sure where you're getting the text from so lets just call that `yourText`.

```
 let yourText = "someTextToMatch";

 //By option text something like this.
 $('#Seltherapist').find('option').each(function(i, v){
     if ($(v).text() === yourText)
     {
         $(v).prop('selected', 'selected');
         return false;
     }
 });

 //by option value
 $('#Seltherapist').val(yourText);
```

Comment: Thank you! I must have tried this 100 times and somehow messed something up. got it working with your help.